# Call a function within a django model

Tags: django

I have a to do list app.  In order to retain a history of Actions completed, I want to create a new instance of the Action any time a task goes from complete to incomplete.  Therefore I will have a copy of every time an Action has been completed.

```
class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Action Name", max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Complete?")

    # And some other attributes

    # Cache initial version of record to determine before/after differences
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        cached_vars = self.__dict__
        super(Action, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        var_cache = {}
        for var in cached_vars:
            var_cache[var] = getattr(self,var)
        self.var_cache = var_cache

    def remove_attrs(self):
        self.complete = True
        #Remove some other attributes

    def save(self, **kw):
        if self.complete:
            # Do some stuff
        else:

            if self.var_cache['complete'] != getattr(self,'complete') and self.id is not None:
                new_obj = deepcopy(self)
                new_obj.id = None
                new_obj.save()

                remove_attrs(self)
```

In the code above, in the save method, if the Action is going from complete to incomplete, the Action makes a deepcopy of itself and then needs to change the value of some its attributes (for instance, there is an attribute that makes the Action reoccur.  I need to turn this off or it will constantly attempt to go from a complete to an incomplete state).

When I call remove_attrs(self), it doesn't appear to work.  How do I call to the def remove_attrs(self)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a method, call it on the object.

```
self.remove_attrs()
```